# mapWithKeys in laravel ,i dont understand how do it work?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I saw the example of laravel, but i dont understand how do it work.

for [this example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-mapwithkeys):

```
$collection = collect([
    [
        'name' => 'John',
        'department' => 'Sales',
        'email' => 'john@example.com'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Jane',
        'department' => 'Marketing',
        'email' => 'jane@example.com'
    ]
]);

$keyed = $collection->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [$item['email'] => $item['name']];
});

$keyed->all();
```

someone can explain detail of it?

Comment: document is pretty self explanatory, just try to play with some of your own data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$collection = collect([
    [
        'name' => 'John',
        'department' => 'Sales',
        'email' => 'john@example.com'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Jane',
        'department' => 'Marketing',
        'email' => 'jane@example.com'
    ]
]);

$keyed = $collection->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
   //this line takes one array of collection object in item array and  make a key of its email and store name on that email key  
    return [$item['email'] => $item['name']];
});

$keyed->all();
```

Comment: it mean call $key of array in collection as $item, right?!

Comment: happy to help..:)

Comment: oop, it same like map method in laravel?!!